Map Not Portraying Same Size Legend or Map Points
I am trying to map different levels of nutrients at different points on a map but for some reason, the breaks in the sizes are not showing up how I want them to in the legend or the map. The code lines below should give me the same size points in the legend and map but they do not. nh4_bottom_june_plot Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?
nox_bottom_june_plot <- map_plot(dat = kd_map[[3]] %>% mutate(kd = (kd)^(1/3)), value = "kd", year = 2023, season = "June", label = "NOx Bottom Nutrients") +
    scale_radius(breaks = (c(0.5, 3, 5.5, 7, 8.5))^(1/3),
                labels =      c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50), range = c(0.5, 8.5)
                , limits = c(0, 51)^(1/3)) +
  guides(size = guide_legend(title = "NOx (μM)"))

nh4_bottom_june_plot <- map_plot(dat = kd_map[[3]] %>% mutate(kd = (kd)^(1/3)), value = "kd", year = 2023, season = "June", label = "NH4 Bottom Nutrients") +
    scale_radius(breaks = (c(0.5, 3, 5.5, 7, 8.5))^(1/3),
                labels =      c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), range = c(0.5, 8.5), limits = c(0, 51)^(1/3)) +
  guides(size = guide_legend(title = "NH4 (μM)"))


I tried to change the breaks and range and neither of them are giving me the outcome I want. The points from plot to plot should be the same range and they are not.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! We don't have your data, so it's really hard to help. You can do dput(kd_map) and paste the results into your question. Also please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Where does map_plot come from?
